# Store variable and Run loop when the game is over

Tags: objective-c

I have made a simple game just to test my knowledge(Similar to flappy bird). When the game is over i'd like to run a loop. The loop would make the bird go down from is current Y position to the Y position i choosed which is 514(to simulate the bird falling down and hitting the ground). This is my GameOver method:

```
-(void)GameOver{

if (ScoreNumber > HighScoreNumber) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ScoreNumber forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
}

[TunnelMovement invalidate];
[BirdMovement invalidate];

Exit.hidden = NO;
/*
TunnelTop.hidden = YES;
TunnelBottom.hidden =YES;
Bird.hidden = YES;
 */

}
```

So i'd like to save the current Y position of the bird. Store that variable and run a loop that would make it go from the current y position to the y position 514. Could someone guide me through that process? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bird is a UIView, eg. a UIImageView, you can just use a UIView animation to that.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             bird.frame = CGRectMake(bird.frame.origin.x, 514, bird.frame.size.width, bird.frame.size.height);
                         }
                         completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
-(void)GameOver
{

    if (ScoreNumber > HighScoreNumber) {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ScoreNumber forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    [TunnelMovement invalidate];
    [BirdMovement invalidate];

    Exit.hidden = NO;
    /*
    TunnelTop.hidden = YES;
    TunnelBottom.hidden =YES;
    Bird.hidden = YES;
    */

  }

  - (void) startGame {
        NSInteger birdYLocation = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
       // assuming xOrigin, width and height are known values
       bird.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, birdYLocation, width, height); 

       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     bird.frame = CGRectMake(bird.frame.origin.x, 514, bird.frame.size.width, bird.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
     }
```